# VirtualBox Package to DL for Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, virtual-machine, mate-desktop

I am trying to decide which edition of VirtualBox to download.

I am currently running **Linux Mint 16 Petra MATE** and am wanting to install Windows 8.1 to a VM to use Visual Studio for some of my course projects...I would rather not dual-boot, I just left dual-boot with a bad experience as my Windows partition ended up with a nasty rundll32.exe virus infection.

When I go to the [Downloads](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) section of VirtualBox's homepage, there isn't a specific package that is for Linux Mint.

Was hoping someone can tell me what version of VirtualBox they're running on Linux Mint?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can install VirtualBox from the package manager GUI or by running

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

If you really want to get the version from the webpage, remember that Mint is based on and completely compatible with Ubuntu so you can use the package for the version of Ubuntu that your Mint is based on. In your case, that's Ubuntu 13.0.

The only other issue is whether your system is 32 or 64 bit. Run `uname -m`, if the output is `x86_64`, you're running a 64 bit system. If it is something like `i386` you're running a 32bit one.

So, get the package for Ubuntu 13.0 and the correct architecture.